# Tkinter getting wrong order of widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, toolbar

I guess this is a very beginners question. I am using Tkinter to get a GUI in Python. But with the code below the frames a displayed in the wrong order.

```
# ********************************************
# * Frame for toolbar                        *
# ********************************************

# Main frame
self.fr_toolbar = Frame(self)
self.fr_toolbar.pack(fill=X)
self.fr_toolbar.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Align toolbars left
self.fr_left = Frame(self.fr_toolbar, bd=1, relief = RAISED)
self.fr_left.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E)

# Align toolbars right
self.fr_right = Frame(self.fr_toolbar, bd = 1, relief = RAISED)
self.fr_right.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)


# *********************************************
# * Communication toolbar                     *
# *********************************************

# Create Frame for comm toolbar
self.tb_comm = Frame(self.fr_left)
self.tb_comm.grid(row=0, column=0)

# Several buttons in here...


# ********************************************
# * Scope toolbar                            *
# ********************************************

# Seperator line
self.fr_split = Frame(self.fr_left, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, width=2, height=28)
self.fr_split.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Create frame for scope toolbar
self.tb_scope = Frame(self.fr_left)
self.tb_scope.grid(row=0, column=2)

# Several buttons in here


# *********************************************
# * Exit tool bar                             *
# *********************************************

# Create frame for exit tool bar
self.tb_exit = Frame(self.fr_right)
self.tb_exit.pack()

# Exit button here
```

The idea was to have the exit toolbar on the right and all other toolbar on the left. So far it works. All toolbar frames inside fr_left are on the lefthand side. tb_exit in fr_right is on the right.

But inside fr_left I get the wrong order to show my toolbars. First I get tb_comm, then tb_scope and as third fr_split even if it is set between the other two toolbars. I tried it with pack() and with grid().

Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong? I thought at least with pack() I will get the widgets in the order I define them. And the same with grid(). I ordered them with column, but Python is ignoring it.

Florian

Comment: Maybe you have second line with `self.fr_split.grid()`

Comment: I'm not sure because I can't reproduce what you're describing in a minimal example.  I'd suggest taking things out one at a time until you figure out exactly where it's not behaving like you expect.

Comment: When I run your code, the order I get is tb_comm, fr_split, then tb_scope, just as the code requests it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you are allowed to hit me! I set the buttons for tb_scope in tb_comm mistakenly. So all toolbars were on the right place but only the buttons were not. As I wrote, beginners fault...

Sorry to steal your time!